# jQuery jTable optgroup

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable, optgroup

I'm trying to create optgroup dropdown but I can't find out what data should I send from server to get result what I want.

```
JobsSelected: {
    title: "Name",
    edit: true,
    create: true,
    list: false,
    inputClass: 'multiselect',
    options: function (data) {
        if (data.source == 'create') {
            data.clearCache();
            return '/Jobs/Options';
        }
    }
},
```

This is jtable code where I call server and get gruped jobs from my DB and want to show them on form.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Options()
{
    var data = jobs.GroupBy(x => x.Department)
                    .Select(g => new {
                        DisplayText = g.Key,
                        Value = g.Select(i => new
                        {
                            DisplayText = i.Name,
                            Value = i.Sifra
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();

    return data;
}
```

This is grouped data from server. But it just shows list with values from g.Key and I need to set that as optgroup. I don't know is it possible this way? How can I achieve that?

Comment: add all your `Jobs` server part please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to display your values as an optgroup for a dropdown in jQuery's jTable is not implemented. You can only display items composed of a `DisplayText` field and `Value`.

If you want to do so, try to customize jTable plugin, as it is available on GitHub.
This should be around `_fillDropDownListWithOptions` function

Answer (score 0):

Slighly modified `jquery.jtable.js` to support `OptGroup` value.

```
    _fillDropDownListWithOptions: function ($select, options, value) {
        $select.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if (options[i].OptGroup) {
                $('<optgroup />').attr('label', options[i].DisplayText)
                    .appendTo($select);
            } else {
                $('<option' + (options[i].Value == value ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + '>' + options[i].DisplayText + '</option>')
                    .val(options[i].Value)
                    .appendTo($select);                
            }
        }
    },
```

Note seems there is not specification about `optgroup` nesting hence only flat options are supported.